# Windows Server 2003/Exchange 2007: How to setup public domain mail.foo.com to route to internal exchange server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, exchange-2007, internal-dns

Good day,
  I have an internal Exchange Server 2007 and a Windows Server 2003 domain. At this point in time I have an external DNS setup (DynDNS 29.95 service) to resolve foo.com to my singular public IP address then it gets routed to external facing site. I would like to know how to setup POP on mail.foo.com and SMTP on smtp.foo.com, and more importantly, what needs to be setup in Exchange server to allow for this to happen. 
  My end state is to send email through smtp.foo.com and receive mail on mail.foo.com. As of now, when I create a user within Exchange the default email address is user@company.domain, and I would like it to be user@foo.com.

Thank you and I appreciate the help as I am a .NET developer trying to do sys admin work, and it is MUCH harder than I have ever imagined, my hat is off to all sys admins and IT pros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that need to happen here.

**Set up your MX record**
You need to create a DNS record of type MX that points to 'mail.foo.com'. This will tell incoming mailers that you receive mail destined for @foo.com at mail.foo.com.

**Set up accepted domains**
In Exchange Console, go to Organization Config -> Hub Transport -> Accepted Domains tab. Make sure that 'foo.com' is in this list, and set to default.

**Set up email address policy**
On the E-mail Addresses tab for Hub Transport, right click on Default Policy and go to Edit. Following this wizard will let you set up what email addresses Exchange assigns to users by default. This is where the choice of firstname.lastname@foo.com vs accountname@foo.com gets made.

**Set up POP3 address**
Create an A record in your DNS that points pop.foo.com to your lone IP address.

**Set up POP3 access**
Poke a hole in your firewall to forward tcp/110 to the server running the Client Access role. Back in Exchange Console, go to Server Configuration -> Your server -> POP3 and IMAP4 tab, select POP3 and click Properties. The defaults are probably OK, but check 'em. We don't use this service so I can't advise.

**Set up incoming SMTP**
DNS is already set so mail.foo.com is pointed at your lone IP address (that's the MX record in step 1). Poke a hole in your firewall to forward tcp/25 to the server running the Edge role (or your spam appliance, if you have one). If you don't have a server in this role, forward it to your Hub Transport server. If you have to use a HT server, you'll need to tell Exchange that it's OK to receive anonymous mail on TCP/25 on that server. To do that open Exchange Console, go to Server Configuration -> Hub Transport -> Your server. Double click on the Default policy. Ensure it is listening on TCP/25, and allows connections from anywhere (these are the defaults). On the Permission Groups tab, make sure the "Anonymous Users" box is checked.

**Set up outbound SMTP**
Create a DNS record for smtp.foo.com pointing to your lone IP address. Poke a hole in your firewall to forward tcp/587 to the server running the Hub Transport role. Go to Server Configuration -> Hub Transport -> Your server. Double click on the Client policy. Ensure it is listening on TCP/587 and allows connections from anywhere (again, these are defaults). On the Permission Groups tab, only Exchange Users should be checked. On the Authentication tab, ensure TLS is turned on. This allows your users to use smtp.foo.com as their mailer, so long as they're logged in.

**Set up TLS access**
This is a tricky thing to do. If you want your users to authenticate securely over the internet (and I bet you do) you'll need to configure a SSL certificate for use by this service. It will make your life a world easier if you get it from one of the major SSL vendors as client applications (including phones) won't complain about invalid certificates. And not all email applications allow importing new certificate authorities. These are called Unified Communication Certificates, and they're more expensive than the standard web-server SSL certs. But they're made for Exchange. You'll need to ensure that mail.foo.com and smtp.foo.com, and maybe webmail.foo.com if you decide to go the OWA route, are on the certificate.

---

That should provide enough hints for where to go from here to at least get you farther down the road. Good luck.

Comment: ...and you rock. Thank you sysadmin1138, I would up this 100x if I could.

Comment: Glad to be of service.